# Registering a callback function in C

Tags: c, callback, kernel, space

I am some Linux kernel space code. I want an application in user space to be able to register a callback function in the kernel space code by calling a function in the kernel space code and passing the address of that callback function. The kernel space code would then execute the callback function at a later time when running. I believe the kernel space code should look something like this:

```
typedef void (*callback_func) (void);
callback_func callback;

static void registerCallBack(callback_func funct){callback = funct;}

//another kernel space method
funct();
```

However, I am a little unsure on the proper typedef and if this will work properly. Can anyone confirm the functionality of this or offer any advice in this area? I am unable to test this right now as I am waiting on the rest of the kernel space code to be finished.

Comment: Looks valid. If you don't want to pass any parameters then you won't even run into troubles with the ABI.

Comment: I'm pretty sure at some point it will need to pass parameters but just for preliminary testing to verify that it works with printk statements none are pass right now.

Comment: I am not sure if you can simply call an userspace function from inside kernel. You must guarantee that you have loaded the same process' address space that gave you the function, and you probably must care if the memory page of the pointer is actually loaded. Address space issues aside, it is completely insecure to enable users to run arbitrary code in kernel space.

Comment: This will eventually be implemented via a library that the user can call functions in. I just need a way to save an address of a function from the user space code so that the kernel code can later run this function. Does this not save the address of that function? I guess I need to remove the static declaration in order to call this function.

Comment: Static declaration has only to do with visibility, not accessibility. If you have a pointer to a static function, you can call it -- if you are in the same processes, in user-mode The kernel can not do it (or at least would be very weird and take a lot of hacking to make it do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly call to a userspace function from the kernel. One possible solution would be to use [signals](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal). From the kernel code you could send a signal to a given process. The signal handler would work then as a sort of callback function.

Comment: Would the same be necessary for the userspace code to send the function's address to the kernel code?

Comment: If, for instance, you are developing a kernel module, you can use a virtual file in order to send and receive data from and into the kernel.

Comment: What about for a device driver? I guess I should've mentioned specifically what I'm doing in kernel space.

Comment: Can you understand what happens if you send a function's address to other process, and try to call it? Do you understand the notion of [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)?

Comment: @user1061166 yeah, I guess you are using a kernel module as a device driver. Can you give more details on what type of interaction do you want between user-space and kernel-space?

Comment: I want the user-space application to save a pointer/address for a function in the application to the driver when the application initializes. When the driver gets a specific interrupt it will run this method (most likely with a tasklet or workqueue as this seems to be the ideal way for an interrupt handler to operate).

I think that this can be done by creating a char device, using signals like you mentioned, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

Your `typedef` looks fine, although I would suggest renaming `callback_func` to something like `callback_func_t`, otherwise it looks like a variable rather than a type.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to run a user-space application from the kernel, then [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html) describes how to do that in detail.